# Grails/GORM: The meaning of belongsTo in 1:N relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In an ordinary one-to-many mapping the "one"-side is the owner of the association. Why would anyone use the belongsTo-mapping for such a mapping? Am I missing some side-effect of specifying belongsTo?

In other words: what are the effects of specifying a belongsTo-mapping in GORM vs. not specifying it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whether to specify *belongsTo* depends upon the type of [referential action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) you want.

If you want Grails to do *On Delete, CASCADE* referential action, then DO specify *belongsTo*. If you want Grails to do *On Delete, RESTRICT* referential action, then DON'T specify *belongsTo*.

e.g.

```
// "belongsTo" makes sense for me here. 
class Country {
  String name
  static hasMany = [states:State]
}

class State {
  String name;
  // I want all states to be deleted when a country is deleted. 
  static belongsTo = Country
}

// Another example, belongsTo doesn't make sense here
class Team {
  String name
  static hasMany = [players:Player]
}

class Player {
   String name
   // I want that a team should not be allowed to be deleted if it has any players, so no "belongsTo" here. 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: may i ask you a question related to belongsTo?

what if i told Player belongsTo Team but I didn't state that Team hasMany Player. if Team were deleted what the happen with Player, are they going to be deleted as well ?

Comment: @nightingale2k1 - I think if you mapped Team-Player that way there would be no association whatsoever between the two, so a player when the corresponding team is deleted

Comment: belongsTo represent the difference between `composition` (with belongsTo) and `aggregation` (without belngsTo)

Answer (score 2):

Specifying belongsTo allows Grails to transparently cascade updates, saves and deletes to the object's children.  Without belongsTo, if you attempt to delete a master record, you'll end up getting a foreign key violation if it has any details it owns.