# Grails understanding belongsTo Association

Tags: grails, associations, grails-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails/GORM: The meaning of belongsTo in 1:N relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654871/grails-gorm-the-meaning-of-belongsto-in-1n-relationships)

I have 2 domain class with belongsTo association

```
      class Teacher {
         String name
         String department
      }

      class Address {
        String line1
        String line2

       // Teacher teacher  //this line is commented.
       static belongsTo = [teacher: Teacher]

        static constraints = {
        }
     }
```

1. What is the advantage i get when i make  Address **belongsTo** Teacher
2. do i need to declare teacher object reference in Address class (see the commented line in Teacher class)

Answer (score 1):

The goal to have the `belongsTo` clause is to have bi-directional access from one class to the other. See [Documentation of belongsTo](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html).

You can omit the second declaring of teacher (you commented out).

So it should look like this:

```
  class Teacher {
     String name
     String department

     Set<Address> adresses = new HashSet<Address>() // here you could set a specific list/set data holder
     static hasMany = [adresses:Address]
  }

  class Address {
    String line1
    String line2

   static belongsTo = [teacher: Teacher]

    static constraints = {
    }
 }
```

Here you have a one-to-many associaton, where both classes have access to each other. If you remove the `belongsTo` clause you can not access the teacher object from the adress object. This is also reflected in the database.

Comment: what if its one-to-one association

Comment: Then its simply [hasOne](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)

Comment: I dont think the goal is to make the relations bidirectional - can't we have bidirectional relation without belongsTo ! what if I declare a variable of type Teacher in Address and not use belongsTo at all !

Comment: @sudhir Yes. Thats a point I not directly mentioned (for this i linked also to the documentation!). But you have to do way more programming task to make an association really biderectional if you not use `hasOne`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Goal of belongsTo isn't making the relations bidirectional - The goal is to specify which side of the association takes the ownership and to define the behavior of cascading save and delete operations

Read this [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html) it explains every thing you need to know about belongsTo.